# Reading PT1000 using op amp

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, sensor, temperature

I am looking for an op-amp circuit that can take in 24 VDC and output 0-10 V. It will be connected to my temperature sensor. I have found one diagram but I believe there should be some changes to it. enter image description here

DETAILS: PT1000 temperature sensor
Supply voltage is 24vdc and output has to be between 0-10v
i prefer using opamp for this purpose, could you please guide if the below circuit is ok

[image]

I can read over the internet that LM358 accepts 24VDC, it ranges upto 32vdc.

Comment: You could use a simulation tool and verify this for yourself if you wanted. That's my recommendation anyway.

Comment: Research [LM358 datasheet](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=lm358+datasheet&t=opera&ia=web) and see the diagram of "comparator with hysteresis."

Comment: Looks like a fine non-inverting amp to me, with a 0.5Volt offset.  I suggest working around a larger offset when using this amp with a single-side supply in order to deal with output range issues.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get a zero output out of this, though.

Comment: ...  and that's not the best way to add an offset to the output.  The output impedance of your offset circuit is too high.

Comment: `and output has to be between 0-10v` I understand that you want an output between 0 and 10V based on temperature sensed by PT-1000. Is that correct? If yes then between what temperatures you want that output range?

Comment: @RohatKılıç 0-50 degree

Comment: @ScottSeidman then how do i read 0v?